# DNS request with scapy (Python)

Tags: python, dns, scapy, nslookup

I wrote a code that creates a dns packet and sends it. The packet simulates the `nslookup -type=soa facebook.com 8.8.8.8` command for example.
But for some reason I get a different answer from what the 'nslookup' command returns.

**my code dns server output: "a.ns.c10r.facebook.com"**

**the dns server from `nslookup -type=soa facebook.com 8.8.8.8` command: "a.ns.facebook.com"**

- my final goal is to get a site dns server so I would be able to get an authoritative answer for the site ip address
  with a dns packet.

this is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSQR
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP

def main():
    dns_server_request = IP(dst='8.8.8.8') / UDP(dport=53) / DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname='www.facebook.com', qtype='SOA'))
    ans = sr1(dns_server_request, verbose=0)
    ans.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

someone know what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

- (the dns server that my code is giving not working by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: You wanted to query the apex domain, facebook.com,
rather than www.

---

> what am I doing wrong

(1.) Well, you're using `nslookup`, for starters. :-)

One can, of course, obtain useful results from that tool
given a bit of care.
But I strongly recommend that you prefer `dig`
for all your interactive queries.
It is a bit like using `tcpdump port domain`,
in that it defaults to showing you *everything*
that came back from the given nameserver.

(2.) The domain you query matters.

Note that "www" is a CNAME pointing
at star-mini.c10r.facebook.com.
And since FB is a large outfit,
it turns out there's a zone cut to support
that part of the namespace,
so it has its own bailiwick.

```
$ dig +noadd any c10r.facebook.com @d.ns.c10r.facebook.com | grep '^c10r' | sort
c10r.facebook.com.  300 IN  SOA a.ns.c10r.facebook.com. dns.facebook.com. 1715184742 300 600 600 300
c10r.facebook.com.  3600    IN  NS  a.ns.c10r.facebook.com.
c10r.facebook.com.  3600    IN  NS  b.ns.c10r.facebook.com.
c10r.facebook.com.  3600    IN  NS  c.ns.c10r.facebook.com.
c10r.facebook.com.  3600    IN  NS  d.ns.c10r.facebook.com.
```

---

Good question!
Kudos for offering us a lovely [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
It's very clear what you're doing,
no need for clarifying comments.

---

It's worth noting that there is no requirement for MNAME
in an SOA to respond to your queries.
It is strictly a private arrangement AXFR detail
that happens to be exposed in query results.
Many zones will have a so-called "hidden master"
that responds to members of the NS set
but won't respond to general inet clients.

When you discover a new zone,
as with that SOA result you posted,
the most appropriate thing to do
is query that zone's NS set and
interrogate its delegated nameservers.
You can of course *also* query the MNAME nameserver,
but don't be surprised if it doesn't answer
or sends back REFUSED.

Note that `dig +trace +norecurse`
can be quite helpful in figuring out
which nameservers are in bailiwick
for some deeply nested zone name.

Comment: thank you very much, I understand why it happened now